# Update panel does not make a postback for user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

The update panel does not make a postback when calling `Update` !

```
<ajax:TabPanel ID="EmployeesTab" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MyUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <GW:MyUserControl ID="MyUserControlId" 
                                     runat="server" /> 
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</ajax:TabPanel>


private void PopulateEmployees()
{
    MyUserControlId.EntityId = SelectedEntity.Id;
    MyUpdatePanel.Update();
}
```

Any help!

Comment: I think its only problem, that u dint set the AutoPostBack="true" in the TabPanel declaration.

Comment: There is no `AutoPostBack` for TabPanel. And I don't want it for whole TabControl

Comment: I'm calling the `PopulateEmployees()` method programmatically, but no Postback is happened when I call `Update` for updatepanel

Answer (score 1):

The UpdatePanel has known problems when inside an AjaxControlToolkit templated control.

This is an old article, but the issue still exists in the current version of the AjaxControlToolkit: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/atlasupdatepanel-template-really-darned-kewl/

The suggested workaround is to wrap the TabPanel in the UpdatePanel rather than vice-versa.

Comment: In response to your comment that you don't want to wrap the whole TabPanel in an UpdatePanel, you might consider using a client-side tab control option like: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/